# Kie workbench and jbpm dashbuilder

Tags: dashboard, jbpm, kie

can someone kindly help me with how I can connect my jbpm dashbuilder to my Kie workbench. 
I would like my tasks and process instances to displayed on the dashboard. for instance, to have the number of tasks, number of instances, active, pending, suspended, etc. I will appreciate this help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to  jbpm dashbuilder or jbpm Dashboard and also give details about the jbpm version so as the details can be provided.

For jbpm Dashboard I hope this will help u https://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v6.0/userguide/chap-bam.html

Answer (score 0):

With 7.2.0, and even with 7.1.0 of JBPM Console, Kie Workbench and Dashboard are integrated.